# Apply action only when in specific Outlook account

Tags: vba, outlook, outlook-2007

I apply a default string to the beginning of the Subject field with all new emails.

I have two Outlook user accounts/PST files - personal & business.  I want the Subject string added to emails only when I'm working in the business account.

```vb
Private Sub Application_ItemSend(ByVal Item As Object, Cancel As Boolean)
If MsgBox("Send with 'Myrtleford Festival" at start of subject?", vbYesNo, "Send as Festival mail") = vbYes Then
    If (Left(Trim(Item.Subject), 11)) <> "The " Then
        Item.Subject = "The Myrtleford Festival 2012/ " + Item.Subject
    End If
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, cool. In fact I stumbled on a totally foolproof & elegant solution. In Outlook's Trust Centre>Macro Security, I selected the option for "warn for all macros". Now when I open Outlook to any of my profiles, I get a pop-up asking if I want to enable/disable macros. Since the VBA script is the only macro running, I can easily filter whether the default subject string is used. Which will work 100% of the time forever (since I can't see any reason why I'll ever be using another macro/VBA script)

Answer (score 0):

This is the basis of an approach.

It is sometime since I have had multiple accounts but, when I did, the top level folders were very different.  The code below outputs to the Immediate window the names of the top level folders.  On my current system this would give:

```
Personal Folders
Archive Folders
Test Folders
```

If your two accounts have different top level folders, you could distinguish your accounts from that.

If you like this approach but the top level folders are the same, I have a routine that searches for a specific folder at any depth in the hierarchy.  Even if the main folders are the same, I assume some of the sub-folders are different.

```
Sub AnswerA()

  Dim InxIFLCrnt As Integer
  Dim TopLvlFolderList As Folders

  Set TopLvlFolderList = _
          CreateObject("Outlook.Application").GetNamespace("MAPI").Folders

  For InxIFLCrnt = 1 To TopLvlFolderList.Count
    Debug.Print TopLvlFolderList(InxIFLCrnt).Name
  Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Tony. Sorry I wrote my question in haste & used the wrong terminology. Actually, I have 2 Outlook profiles, each with a separate .pst file. I only want the VBA routine to be applied when I'm working in one of those profiles. Kirk

Comment: That is what I thought you meant.  I assume the folder structures in the two PST files are different.  If this is so, you can distinguish them by the presence or absence of a particular folder.  The code above only looks at the top level folders.  Perhaps this is enough.  If not, I can add another routine to my answer that searches the entire hierarchy.